# How do I add an existing custom domain email to my gmail inbox without Workspace?

Tags: gmail, email, smtp

I have a website with node.js deployed on AWS Amplify. Right now, I have mx records that merely forward mail to a gmail address. I want a gmail inbox that I can send emails from without using Google Workspace.

I'm okay with coding things myself if necessary.

Is using SMTP with TLS the only option?

Comment: The "other answers" are wrong. The correct answer is use AWS SES or similar